# Select value from select case

Tags: mysql, case

The code below is workable in MySQL. However, I wonder that if I have more groups to choose from or I can save time when running the program. Because it selects the group I want for the first time and then changes the value to create a column for the second time. Thank you.

```
Groups:
Group_1：('F01', 'D01')
Group_2：('F01', 'B01')
Group_3: ('B01', 'D01')
```

```
SELECT O.OrderNumber, CONVERT(date,O.OrderDate) AS Date,
       P.ProductName, I.Quantity, I.UnitPrice, 
       CASE WHEN P.ProductSection_ID = 'F01' THEN 'Frozen food section' 
            WHEN P.ProductSection_ID = 'B01' THEN 'Body and beauty section' 
            WHEN P.ProductSection_ID = 'D01' THEN 'Deli section'
            END AS `ProductSection`
  FROM Order AS O
  JOIN OrderItem AS I ON O.Id = I.OrderId
  JOIN Product AS P ON P.Id = I.ProductIdAND
  WHERE
   If('GROUP_1' = ?group, P.ProductSection_ID in ('F01', 'D01'), P.ProductSection_ID in ('F01', 'B01'))
ORDER BY O.OrderNumber
```

I use Tibco to extract data from SQL. MySQL code can be run on the software and ?group will be seen as properties to choose the data I want(group1, group2 or group3).If I replace ?group with `GROUP_2` below, it will select group2. 
`If('GROUP_1' = ?group, P.ProductSection_ID in ('F01', 'D01'), P.ProductSection_ID in ('F01', 'B01'))`

If I use replace ?group with `GROUP_1` below, it will select group1.
`If('GROUP_1' = ?group, P.ProductSection_ID in ('F01', 'D01'), P.ProductSection_ID in ('F01', 'B01'))`

However, if I have more than three groups, it is a bad method to use "IF". So, I wonder if there is a better method. Thanks.

Comment: What is the question, or what is wrong with your code?  Your code actually looks like SQL Server to me, by the way.

Comment: sorry, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, this is not sql server.

Comment: Well, order is a reserved word, so it ain't MySQL

Comment: your where condition is notb clear ..  you can't change the value in where clause  ..  where clause just check if a rows must be selected  or not  .. try add  a proper data sample and your expected  result

Comment: If('GROUP_1' = ????, P.ProductSection_ID in ('F01', 'D01'), P.ProductSection_ID in ('F01', 'B01'))
ORDER BY O.OrderNumber
I want to change the value here(???) to change the group I select. If I have more than two groups, what should I do to chage the MySQL code?